# настроить react hook form стилизовать контрол из радио в button

Tags: javascript, react-hook-form

я использую useFieldArray в react hook form
у меня есть следующий код

```
  <Typography mb={1} mt={3} typography="h3">
    {groupTitle}
  </Typography>
  {fields.map((item, index) => (
    <Box key={item.id}>
      <Box
        display="flex"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="space-between"
        mb={1}
      >
        <RadioGroup defaultValue="VH">
          <Box display="flex">
            <FormControlLabel
              {...register(`clones.${index}.chain`, refType)}
              value="VH"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="VH"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              {...register(`clones.${index}.chain`, refType)}
              value="VL"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="VL"
            />
          </Box>
        </RadioGroup>
        <TextField
          placeholder="Имя клона"
          fullWidth
          sx={{ margin: '0 0 0 16px' }}
          size="medium"
          {...register(`clones.${index}.clone_name`, refType)}
        />

        <IconButton
          disabled={fields.length <= 1}
          onClick={() => remove(index)}
        >
          <ClearIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>
```

здесь текстовое поле и радио батон и все работает отлично поля можно добавлять и значения уходят на бэк массивом, в массиве столько объектов, сколько я добавил, у каждого объекта есть поля chain - это из радио батона  и clone_name это из текстового поля, но по дизайну нужно чтобы здесь были не радиобатоны, а кнопки и чтобы кнопки вели себя так будто это радиобатон, то есть одну нажал - другая отключилась, это очен похоже на ToggleButtonGroup, я бы сделал это без проблем, если бы не запутанная схема во всех этих реакт хук формах, суть в том, что мне нужно в FormControlLabel передать Button или ToggleButton и чтобы  {...register(`clones.${index}.chain`, refType)} это также работало, то есть значения нажатой кнопки должно передаваться на бэк, если я просто делаю так

```
    <FormControlLabel
      {...register(`clones.${index}.chain`, refType)}
      value="VL"
      control={<Button />}
      label="VL"
    />
```

то значения на бэк не уходят или может как вариант стилизовать как-то этот Radio, чтобы он был свиду как кнопка, НО как я понял нельзя использовать стейт, ибо когда я добавляю несколко таких групп кнопок, то стейт работает не корректно, если я выбрал одну кнопку, то вторая переключается на тоже положение, кто знаком с react hook form^ http i need somebody)